# How to mimic asp.net get set in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to mimic asp.net `get{}` `set{}` in rails, here is what i tried in my controller:

```
def get_segment=(segment)
    if params[:s] != nil
      segment = params[:s]
    else
      segment = "personal"
    end
end
```

Then i am trying to access it like this:

```
@something = get_segment
```

But it always returns as `nil`.

How can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to mimic `get{}` `set{}` in C#, the property `Segment`

```cs
private string _segment;
public string Segment {
    get { return _segment; }
    set { _segment = value; }
}
```

is written as followed in Ruby:

```rb
# get
def segment
    @segment
end

# set
def segment=(value)
    @segment = value
end

# if you don't have additional logic, you can just write
attr_accessor :segment
```

Then you can use `some_instance.segment` to retrieve the value and `some_instance.segment = some_value` to modify the value.

According to your code sample above, you want to fetch `s` parameter with a default value if it doesn't exist. You should define a getter, not in the setter form as you have provided.

```rb
def get_segment     # or just "segment"
    params[:s] || "personal"
end
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what i needed, But what if i want to match the params to an array. Meaning that this array should contain the params value else resort to default value?

Comment: Did you mean pass in the parameters as `some_url?s[]=foo&s[]=bar` and retrieve the array `['foo', 'bar']` from `params[:s]`?

Comment: I meant checking that the `params[:s]` is contained within the array. If not it should have a default value.

Comment: @Whatever `some_array.include?(params[:s]) ? params[:s] : 'default value'`, you should read some API documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using get segment=(segment)?

look like what you are wanting to do is test params[:s], so the = is uncessary, as is the segment parameter.

```
def get_segment
    if params[:s] != nil
      params[:s]
    else
      "personal"
    end
end
```

I think this would give you what you want.